# Determining whether a file path or Url is being passed to command line argument

Tags: java, exception, command

I'm trying to work on an assignment where I have to pass either a file or url to command line args, and I print out the text passed in the arg. But how can I determine whether the argument I'm passing is either a local file or a url without checking the string of the args?

Comment: Just use Pattern matcher....url for example in case of http starts with either http or https.

Comment: @JunedAhsan thx for your input, but doesn't pattern matcher check the string. either way, the way i have to determine what the argument is can't include checking its text ( .contains, Pattern matcher..).